# Change bg color and inner text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to make a simple bg randomizer project that also updates the h1 text with the rgb code of the randomized color.

I can't seem to find a solution as to why doesn't this work:

```
const button= document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
    let r= math.floor((Math.random()+254)+1);
    let g= math.floor((Math.random()+254)+1);
    let b= math.floor((Math.random()+254)+1);
    body.style.backgroundColor(rgb(r,g,b));
    h1.innerText(`rgb(${r},${g},${b})`);
})
```

Comment: `Math.floor`, with capital "M", `body.style.backgroundColor = ` instead of `body.style.backgroundColor()` and `h1.innerText = ` instead of `h1.innerText()`

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ is not a suitable problem description. What should happen? What happens instead? Any error messages you can share (and there will definitely be errors in the console)? -> [mcve]

Comment: Javascript is a case-sensitive about variables names. So, this is `Math` with an uppercase. Also the way you"re trying to get a value between 1 and 255 is erroneous. also backgroundColor isn't set properly, it takes a string value and rgb() isn't defined. Last, neither `body` and `h1` are addressed properly.

Comment: MDN provides a [very-well written documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for Javascript. You can use it to resolve further bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code changes the color.

Seems like multiple issue

```
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
let r= math.floor((Math.random()+254)+1);
let g= math.floor((Math.random()+254)+1);
let b= math.floor((Math.random()+254)+1);
body.style.backgroundColor(rgb(r,g,b));
h1.innerText(`rgb(${r},${g},${b})`);
```

1. body is not defined
2. `backgroundColor` is not a function
3. `rgb` is not defined
4. `innerText` is not a function

```js
const button= document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
    let r= Math.floor((Math.random()*254)+1);
    let g= Math.floor((Math.random()*254)+1);
    let b= Math.floor((Math.random()*254)+1);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
    h1.innerText = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
})
```

```html
<body>

 <h1>Test Color</h1>

 <button>Change Color</button>

</body>
```

Comment: `const body = document.body;` - Why an extra variable when there's only one occurrence of `body` in the event handler?

Comment: yes! no need to create one extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

`body.style.backgroundColor` is a property not a function.
Try `body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(${r},${g},${b})"`